# Linux/Bash - Create Loop for "find" to output to a file

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Apologies if this has been answered, I'm somewhat new to Linux but I didn't see anything here that was on target.

Anyway, I'm running this command:

```
find 2013-12-28 -name '*.gz' | xargs zcat | gzip > /fast/me/2013-12-28.csv.gz
```

The issue is that I need to run this command for about 250 distinct dates, so doing this one at a time is quite tedious.

What I want to do is have a script that will increment the date by 1 day after the "find" and in the file name. I really don't even know what this would look like, what commands to use, etc.

Background:

The find command is being used in a folder that's full of folders, each for 1 day of data. Each day's folder contains 24 subfolders, with each subfolder containing about 100 gzipped CSV files. So the find command is necessary 2 levels up from the folder because it will scan through each folder to combine all the data. The end result is that all the zipped up files are combined into 1 large zipped up file.

If anyone can help it would be hugely appreciated, otherwise I have about 250 more commands to execute, which obviously will suck.

Comment: Do these top-level folders contain the dates in their names? That would make things easier.

Comment: Hi eigenchris, yes they do.

Comment: Hi eigenchris, yes the top level folders are all named like "2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", etc. The subfolders are named "0-0", "0-1", "0-2", etc. The actual files look like "00:00:00.csv.gz", "00:05:00.csv.gz", "00:10:00.csv.gz", etc.

Comment: Are there actually dates being left out (excluded)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
prev_date="2013-12-28"
for i in {0..250}; do
    next_date=$(date -d"$prev_date +1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
    prev_date=$next_date
    find $next_date -name '*.gz' | xargs zcat | gzip > /fast/me/$next_date.csv.gz
done
```

It should iterate through 250 dates like:

```
2014-08-27
2014-08-28
2014-08-29
2014-08-30
2014-08-31
2014-09-01
2014-09-02
2014-09-03
2014-09-04
2014-09-05
```

Comment: Hmm it made the files ok, but it didn't seem to execute the find command correctly. The output files should be between 500 MB and 1.5 GB, but the ones it made are empty.

Comment: Thanks for that though! Awesome stuff :)

Comment: ok it worked! thanks so much! i just had to remove the quotes in the 4th line around $next_date

Answer (score 0):

jmunsch's solution works very well if the dates are sequential. Otherwise you could do this:

(edited to replace dash characters with colons)

```
for folderName in $(find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 )
do
   date=$(basename $folderName)
   dateWithColons=$(echo $date | sed "s#-#:#g")  # this will replace - with :
   find "$folderName" -name '*.gz' | xargs zcat | gzip > /fast/me/$dateWithColons.csv.gz
done
```